# Como mover um arquivo para uma pasta que o próprio código criou? (python)

Tags: python

Boa tarde pessoal. Escrevi um programa para que, após o usuário inserir um nome, uma pasta com este nome será criada e, então, um arquivo (de outra pasta) será movido para ele. A pasta é criada, mas estou recebendo um erro ao tentar mover o arquivo.

```
import os, shutil

digitar = input()

try:
  if not os.path.exists('G:\\Meu Drive\\help\\jordan\\2. Contas\\'+digitar):
    os.makedirs('G:\\Meu Drive\\help\\jordan\\2. Contas\\'+digitar)
except OSError:
  print ('Error: Creating directory. ' +'G:\\Meu Drive\\help\\jordan\\2. Contas\\'+digitar)

shutil.move('G:\\Meu Drive\\help\\3. Apoio\\0. Templates\\Experiência\\Cópia - TEMPLATE.gsheet', 'G:\\Meu Drive\\help\\jordan\\2. Contas\\'+digitar)
```

> OSError: [WinError 87] Parâmetro incorreto: 'G:\Meu Drive\help\3. Apoio\0. Templates\Experiência\Cópia - TEMPLATE.gsheet' -> 'G:\Meu Drive\help\jordan\2. Contas\exemplo'

Porque estou recebendo este erro se estou chamando a variável "digitar" da mesma forma como criei a pasta? Alguém tem alguma dica?

Olhei as seguintes perguntas, por serem parecidas com a minha, mas não ajudaram

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16868764/how-to-create-folders-and-move-files-based-on-file-name

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12517451/automatically-creating-directories-with-file-output

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9717411/python-create-directory-and-move-specific-file

Comment: procure saber algo a respeito das permissões de leitura, gravação e modificação na pasta.

Comment: Tenho permissão para ler, gravar, modificar e até excluir a pasta.

Comment: Uma coisa que costuma dar problema é a acentuação. Tente fazer um teste usando somente pastas que não tem acento, e veja o que acontece. Outra coisa é que o `os.path.exists` só verifica se existe, ele não verifica se é um diretório, portanto, se você tiver um arquivo chamado `exemplo` nessa pasta, vai dar erro ao mover porque não é um diretório.

Comment: Uma dica, ao invés do operador `+` use `os.path.join()` para juntar caminhos - funciona multiplataforma e ele trata a existência da barra final para você automaticamente.

Comment: O os.path.exists está ali para criar a pasta com o nome proveniente do input, que no caso utilizado para demonstrar o erro foi "exemplo". Experimentei utilizar o os.path.join() no lugar do último operador + do meu código, porém foi acusado sintaxe inválida.

Comment: @JordanGarcia o uso seria assim: `os.path.join(r'G:\Meu Drive\help\jordan\2. Contas', digitar)`

Comment: @nosklo eu ainda estou confuso. Como desta forma o código vai entender que quero enviar especificamente o arquivo "Cópia - TEMPLATE.gsheet" pra pasta recém-criada? Peço desculpas de antemão, pois é a primeira vez que uso os.path e shutil

Comment: @JordanGarcia essa dica do `.join()` não é relacionada com o seu problema - é só uma forma mais segura e direta de juntar dois pedaços de um caminho de diretórios... desculpe se pareceu que iria resolver o problema. As sugestões que eu tenho para resolver o problema em si são: 1) tentar com pastas sem nenhuma acentuação 2) verificar se existe um arquivo chamado `exemplo` que está atrapalhando a criação da pasta.